# error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Event' in augular

Tags: angular

Here is my HTML code. I got an error like we don't have value property for event.

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ol class="form-group">
        <mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="quiz-form-radio-group" formControlName="answer" name="answer" (change)="radioChange($event.value)" required>
            <div class="radio-options" *ngFor="let option of question.options">
                <mat-radio-button name="option-radio-button" class="option1" [value]="option.optionValue" [checked]="question.selectedOption == option.optionText" [ngClass]="{'is-correct': isCorrect(option.optionValue),
                                       'is-incorrect': isIncorrect(option.optionValue)}">
                    <li>{{ option.optionText }}</li>
                    <mat-icon class="feedback-icon" *ngIf="isCorrect(option.optionValue)">done</mat-icon>
                    <mat-icon class="feedback-icon" *ngIf="isIncorrect(option.optionValue)">clear</mat-icon>
                </mat-radio-button>
                <section class="messages">
                    <div *ngIf="isCorrect(option.optionValue) && !!isIncorrect(option.optionValue)">
                        <mat-icon class="sentiment">sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <pre class="message correct-message">  You&apos;re right! The correct answer is Option {{ question.answer }}.</pre>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="isIncorrect(option.optionValue)">
                        <mat-icon class="sentiment">sentiment_very_dissatisfied</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <pre class="message wrong-message">  That&apos;s wrong. The correct answer is Option {{ question.answer }}.</pre>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </mat-radio-group>
    </ol>
</form>
```

I just want to know what is the alternative way to implement that.

Comment: Please add the exact position of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it in two times :

.html

```
<mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="quiz-form-radio-group" formControlName="answer" name="answer" (change)="radioChange(this.getValue($event))" required>
```

and .ts

```
getValue(event: Event): string {
  return (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
}
```

Comment: R, Thanks, ok let me try with this.